# Package Python Pipenv project for AWS Lambda

Tags: python, aws-lambda, pipenv

I have a python project and I am using pipenv to handle deps.

I need to create a zip file that includes the source code and all the dependencies code as well. I need this zip file for uploading it to AWS Lambda.

When working with pipenv, it downloads the dependency libraries somewhere in the computer, but for packaging/distribution of the project I need all the necessary code to be contained in the same place (a zip file).

Is there a way to run pipenv and set it to install dependencies at a specific path? If not, does someone knows where those dependencies are located in my machine?

Thanks

Answer (score 18):

This has worked for me:

```
#!/bin/bash

# this is b/c pipenv stores the virtual env in a different
# directory so we need to get the path to it
SITE_PACKAGES=$(pipenv --venv)/lib/python3.6/site-packages
echo "Library Location: $SITE_PACKAGES"
DIR=$(pwd)

# Make sure pipenv is good to go
echo "Do fresh install to make sure everything is there"
pipenv install

cd $SITE_PACKAGES
zip -r9 $DIR/package.zip *

cd $DIR
zip -g package.zip posts.py
```

I've specifically tried it with numpy and it works correctly. It includes the .so files as well which is great because everything is self contained.

Comment: This would pack all packages under SITE_PACKAGES. The final zip file could contain a lot unused packages ?

Comment: No because SITE_PACKAGES is specific to the Pipenv, so it will only install packages/dependencies necessary for your Pipenv environment.